# Import "ss" error whilt using statsmodels in python

Tags: python

i am trying to run statsmodel package with below command  but failed to import statsmodels:-

```
    from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import ARMA
```

but i am getting the import error :-

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import ARMA
  File "D:\Winpython\python-3.5.1\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\ar_model.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy.stats import norm, ss as sumofsq
ImportError: cannot import name 'ss'
```

I have scipy 1.2.0 and statsmodels 0.6.1 . Can anyone guide me how to resolve this ?

Comment: Update your packages. statsmodels 0.6.1 is 5 years old.

Comment: I have upgrade but then i get :- ImportError: cannot import name 'getargspec'

Comment: Sounds like either you named a file `inspect.py` (don't do that), or you screwed up your Python installation.